# How would you measure static electric charge in the wild?

Tags: electrostatics, experimental-physics, charge

In the early 1990's I saw an extreme example of static electricity. It was in a university library. I would walk in and walk normally for 5 minutes. Then when I tried to walk out, if I touched the metal pole where people submitted books, I would get a massive static electricity shock. Not just a spark. But a massive blueish white bolt that hurt a lot. Every day that I walked in this happened.

My question is: how would you measure the static electricity force involved? You have two issues [1] You don't know exactly when the static charge will occur and [2] then you have to have some way of measuring it. It's not nice and predictable like a Van De Graff Generator.

Answer (score 1):

the measurement tool is called an *electrostatic voltmeter*. I do not know if any exist that you could slip into and out of your pocket to make field measurements though.

Comment: They are too big to carry?

Comment: The voltages involved might be much higher than the maximum that the electrostatic voltmeter is designed to measure?

Comment: yes, but that's where you would start....